# Vertical alignment for columns of text when using the column-count css tag?

Tags: html, css

I am using the CSS column-count tag to divide some text up into four columns on an HTML page.

The first column is vertically always a little bit lower than the other three.

I've boiled it down to the simplest possible example, which you can see below, or in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ge8axq4b/1/).

Why does the first column have extra space at the top?  How do I get them to align?

```css
.column-text{
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 10px;
  column-rule: 1px dotted #d5d5d5;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-text">
  <div>
    <p>Why am I lower</p>
    <p><i>Blah blah blah</i></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Blah blah</p>
    <p><i>Blah blah blah</i></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Blah blah</p>
    <p><i>Blah blah blah</i></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Blah blah</p>
    <p><i>Blah blah blah</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a margin added at the first paragraph. you can remove it by adding this line to the CSS: `.column-text div:first-child p:first-child { margin: 0; }`

```css
.column-text{
  column-count: 4;
  column-gap: 10px;
  column-rule: 1px dotted #d5d5d5;
  font-size: large;
}

.column-text div:first-child p:first-child {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-text">
  <div>
    <p>Why am I lower</p>
    <p><i>Blah blah blah</i></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Blah blah</p>
    <p><i>Blah blah blah</i></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Blah blah</p>
    <p><i>Blah blah blah</i></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Blah blah</p>
    <p><i>Blah blah blah</i></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Why was a margin added to the first paragraph?  Is that just a "feature" of column-count?

Comment: yes its a default margin behavior. Glad that it worked, please mark it as the anwser if that solves your problem.

Comment: Gladly!  Any idea why this default margin behavior only affects the very first <p>, and not the others?

Answer (score 0):

This is a vertical margin of `<p>` tags. In other cases, they collapse - this is the standard behavior of margin.

Comment: Fair enough, but why does it only affect the first one?

Comment: @JosephStyons This applies to everyone. View the result of your code execution in the developer panel, where the block sizes are shown.

Answer (score -1):

In js fiddle it looks like the margins of the other ones are sort of overlapping the parent container.

You could try this

```
.column-text p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

this should make them all look the same

Comment: they are not overlapping, it's a default margin behavior. And why change a paragraph to an inline table which causes its very own kind issues?

Comment: I appreciate the response, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: true i changed it to inline-block.

Comment: inline-block does get rid of the margin, but it has the side effect of wrapping the text different columns into each other.